Is it possible to send a notification without knowing the Firebase token and without subscribing to a topic?
I would like to ask if it's possible to achieve the same thing through the API.
If I am using Firebase Console, notifications can be sent separately to Android and iOS devices to achieve sending to all users. However, I saw the following article in the official documentation, which specifically mentions that one must use a token, topic, or condition to send notifications. Still, I hold out hope and want to know if there is a way, similar to the Firebase Console backend, to send messages to all devices without knowing the token and without subscribing to a topic, once the Firebase token has been initialized.

Nope, nothing like that exists. The most common is to use an all topic for this use-case, and subscribe all clients to that.
